# What can I do? Installing software "E: Unable to fetch some archives" (Pure Data)

Tags: software-installation, bash, puredata

I'm trying to install Pure Data on my Pi with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install puredata
```

However, it isn't working and I'm getting the message:

```
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried those things, as well as various other things I could find on the web, and still nothing worked. I would appreciate your suggestions on what to do?

Thanks

Comment: what does the PureData website say?

Comment: It says how to install Pure Data. To be honest, Pure Data is quite poorly documented anyway, so expecting them to have written anything about this isn't really clever. Maybe I will just try to install it from a package but for various reasons I was hoping this would work.